# Merging multiple associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not quite sure how to do this. Let's say I have 2 associative arrays

```
$arr1 = array('a' => "1", 'b' => "2", 'c' => "3");
$arr2 = array('a' => "9", 'b' => "8", 'c' => "7");
```

How could I possibly produce an "add-up" array as below

```
$arr1 = array(
  array('a', "1", "9"),
  array('b', "2", "8"),
  array('c', "3", "7")
);
```

I'm not sure if the above syntax is correct. If it's not, then an add-up that looks like below will do too

```
$arr1 = array(
  'a' => array("1", "9"),
  'b' => array("2", "8"),
  'c' => array("3", "7")
);
```

Thanks

Comment: don't you mean `array('a' => array('1', '9'), ...` ?

Comment: @SilentGhost, Probably. I don't have much experience with multiple nested levels of associative arrays. But your format should do the job too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr1 = array('a' => "1", 'b' => "2", 'c' => "3");
$arr2 = array('a' => "9", 'b' => "8", 'c' => "7");

$summ=array();
foreach(array($arr1,$arr2) as $arr){
    $keys=array_keys($arr);
    foreach($keys as $key){
        if(isset($summ[$key]))
            $summ[$key][]=$arr[$key];
        else $summ[$key]=array($arr[$key];
    }
}
/*
This will have made:
$sum = array(  
    'a' => array("1", "9"),  
    'b' => array("2", "8"),  
    'c' => array("3", "7")
);

I leave it up to you to now reduce this one more step to match your desired output.
*/
```

Comment: SilentGhost had the better one if it is just 2 arrays and they have the same keys.  If the keys may vary or you need to scale from 2 arrays then this is closer to what you need.

Comment: Good point. I think they probably may vary. For example 1 array could have a b d (no c), but the other a b c (no d). In this case, I will need it as a b c d but with blanks inserted for whatever is missing for one or the other. You say this will do better than the other?

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v) {
    $new[$k] = array($v, $arr2[$k]);
}
```

Is what I think you want. But if I'm mistaken, then you could do:

```
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v) {
    $new[] = array($k, $v, $arr2[$k]);
}
```

Comment: your second form will generate what he was looking for.

This assumes that both associative arrays will have the same keys.

Comment: true, it never been intended to be more sophisticated. It's fairly easy to do produce more general solution, not sure OP needs it.

Comment: Thanks to both of you :) I tested, and it looks like Ben's answer fits it better, but I still have a small bug with the blanks. I'll open another question